# Add additional SE sites to Triage > Unsalvageable > should be closed > off topic because > belongs on another site

Tags: feature-request

When processing review queues, I would like to see more (all?) the possible SE sites listed, so that I can refer someone that has a Question that should be migrated to another SE site, to that site.

Currently the choices available are a hard-coded subset of what is available

```
meta.stackoverflow.com
superuser.com
tex.stackexchange.com
dba.stackexchange.com
stats.stackexchange.com
```

I'd rather have a drop-down, that lists all the StackExchange choices available.

Some people ask about algorithm complexity, would want to be able to suggest the computer science SO site

Some people ask about installing software on linux, want to be able to suggest the question get migrated to unix.stackexchange.com

...and so on.

Comment: As a rule, we try not to migrate crap.  So most user's best bet is to delete their question here, and ask it in the appropriate spot.

Answer (score 6):

## No.

To be able to determine if a question should go on another site at all, one has to have domain knowledge of that site and what kinds of questions it accepts.

Reviewers aren't expected to have that domain knowledge.  They're expected to determine if the question is objectively good, objectively bad, or could do with some editing to get it over to "objectively good".

Just thinking that a question is about Linux or is about Security doesn't automatically make it on-topic on those sites, nor does it make it explicitly off-topic *here*, either.

Comment: And yet, it is already a "feature" that a Review Queue participant already has, but with a hard-coded subset of all the available SE sites....

Comment: So, to support this answer, then the entire ability to suggest "migration" should be removed from what an RQ-er can do.

Comment: @mrflash818:  Migration at a base does require that you understand what's on-topic for the target site.  They can *reject* your migrations.

Comment: I'd argue that migration as it stands probably needs an overhaul, and removing it from the review queues may not be the worst idea.  However, given that it takes four votes to migrate something over successfully, I haven't seen many cases in which reviewers have migrated something that shouldn't have been migrated at all that weren't dealt with quickly.

Comment: I wasn't thinking about auto-migration. I was thinking that someone asking how to compile X on linux as a Quesiton to SO, when I was processing that question in a RQ, could have a boilerplate suggestion to them to go ask on unix.stackexchange.com, for example. I didnt consider that RQ-ers be able to auto-migrate the question _to_ unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Two things there - why would a compilation question *ever* go on Unix.SE?  Also, comments are probably the worst thing you could use here - they're (to be blunt) garbage at instructing what should happen next as a natural course of action.

Comment: Understood. Asked; received feedback; done.

Comment: "You'll find that many of the truths we cling to depend greatly on our own point of view." -- Obi-Wan Kenobi, StarWars